# Removing a repeated value in a row

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have two columns in a data frame that may or may not have copied values in them. If the second column has the same value as the first column, I would like to replace that value with a NULL value or a string indicating the value has been replaced. If the values are different, I want to keep both of those values. For example:
I want to take this

```
col_1      col_2
a            a
a            b
b            d
c            c
c            d
c            c
a            a
```

And turn this into:

```
col_1      col_2
a            NULL
a            b
b            d
c            NULL
c            d
c            NULL
a            NULL
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try:

```
#Code
df$col_2 <- ifelse(df$col_2==df$col_1,'NULL',df$col_2)
```

Output:

```
df
  col_1 col_2
1     a  NULL
2     a     b
3     b     d
4     c  NULL
5     c     d
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(col_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), col_2 = c("a", 
"b", "d", "c", "d")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Another option can be, using correct `R` sintax:

```
#Code2
df$col_2[df$col_2==df$col_1]<-'NULL'
```

Same output.

Using the `ifelse()` approach, we get this:

```
df
  col_1 col_2
1     a  NULL
2     a     b
3     b     d
4     c  NULL
5     c     d
6     c  NULL
7     a  NULL
```

Comment: This does not seem to work if there are combination of col_1 and col_2 repeated. How can I change your answer to accommodate that?

Comment: @Alokin The `ifelse()` approach can work, could you give a sample of data with the issue you mentioned?

Comment: @Alokin I have executed both codes over your new data, and they produced the output you included. What is the issue?

Comment: I think that was my mistake. I fumbled the code. Your answer works, thank you Duck.

Comment: @Alokin Great! Many thanks, also upvoted your question as it is well researched and defined :)

Answer (score 1):

By NULL value, I assume you need NA, if you need actual string NULL, you can use 'NULL' in place of NA_character_ as in Duck's answer.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
mutate(col_2 = case_when(col_1 == col_2 ~ NA_character_, TRUE ~ col_2))
# A tibble: 5 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  col_1 col_2
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     NA   
2 a     b    
3 b     d    
4 c     NA   
5 c     d
```

Based on new input:

```
df %>% mutate(col_2 = case_when(col_1 == col_2 ~ NA_character_, TRUE ~ col_2))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  col_1 col_2
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     NA   
2 a     b    
3 b     d    
4 c     NA   
5 c     d    
6 c     NA   
7 a     NA
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  col_1 col_2
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     a    
2 a     b    
3 b     d    
4 c     c    
5 c     d    
6 c     c    
7 a     a
```

Comment: This only works if there is no repetition in the table. What would you do if some of the pairs are repeated like so:


  col_1 col_2
  <chr> <chr>
1 a     a 
2 a     b    
3 b     d    
4 c     c 
5 c     d
6a      a

Comment: @Alokin, have updated my answer, please check if that works the same.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table` methods which is fast and efficient

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[col_1 == col_2, col_2 := 'NULL']
```

-output

```
df
#   col_1 col_2
#1:     a  NULL
#2:     a     b
#3:     b     d
#4:     c  NULL
#5:     c     d
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(col_1 = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "c"), col_2 = c("a", 
"b", "d", "c", "d")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```